# Punching a hole in a picture

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

[image]I have an imported picture, which I want to punch rectangular holes in.

Trying many options from Youtube or the Adobe website don't seem to work.

When I try to use a Compound Path, for example, it states that the picture is not a path or it was brushed on.

Help or advice is appreciated.

(I am using Adobe Illustrator)

In the picture below, the black rectangles are what I am trying to create holes in.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid no one here can really help either unless you [**edit the question**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/159120/edit) to include what software you may be using.

Comment: I am using Adobe Illustrator, and added it. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Are you trying to "punch holes" in a placed **raster** image? It'd help if you could add a screenshot as an example of what you want to punch holes in.. it doesn't have to be the *actual* art you are working on, just some random sample.

Comment: It's a Roblox Shirt Template. You can search it up, and then go to the first link.

Comment: Please understand that I *want* to help you...I'm not sitting at your desk. I can't see the file open in front of you. I have *no clue* what you are working with and ultimately trying to accomplish. Searching for some link does *not* explain the nature of your objects in Illustrator (vector/raster) or what "holes" you are trying to "punch in". I need to **see** want you are working with or a similar sample. If you can't be bothered to explain ... well...

Comment: Can you do a screen shot and share it here?  We need to see something. Thanks

Comment: If it's an image ( a raster image, like a photograph), then you will probably need to use an opacity mask to make holes in it.  You can't use vector boolean operations on a raster image.

Comment: Clipping masks will work on a raster image.. but again.. kinda need to see an example in order to explain.

Comment: I'll attempt to add a picture, although I will have to work a bit with the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. thanks for adding the screenshot.

I'll explain how to "punch holes" in the raster image below, but....

The *reality* is if I were working on this I would *not* use the raster image. I would just **redraw all of the rectangles** merely using the raster image as a *guide*. It's easy enough to create rectangles in the same layout.

[image]

Having the forms as native *vector* objects frees you to do whatever you want to them directly.

---

##### To work with a raster image...

In order to "punch holes" in it using Illustrator, you need to use a **Clipping Mask**. It's *not possible* to merely "erase" parts of raster images in Illustrator. The best you can do is *hide* portions by masking them.

- Draw rectangles (or any shape) where you want "holes" and a big rectangle which is *outside* the dimensions of the raster image. Here, I've drawn 4 rectangles and given them a Magenta stroke so you can see them...
  [image]
- Make certain the inner, small, shapes are **above** the large outer rectangle in the stacking order. (i.e. bring them all to front `Object > Arrange > Bring to Front`)
- Select all the shapes you've drawn. Here, I've reverse the fill/stroke so they are all filled shapes. 
  [image]
- From the **Menu**, choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`
  [image]
- You should see "holes" appear in the big, outer, rectangle... 
  [image]
- Select this big compound shape **and** the underlying raster image.
- From the **Menu** choose `Object > Clipping mask > Make...`
  [image]
- You should now see "holes" in the raster image...
  [image]
  <sub>(The yellow-green background is used to show where there is transparency.)</sub>

With clipping mask shapes, anything which is *covered* by the original shape will be *visible* when the clipping mask is created using that shape.

---

Comment: Thanks! :) This should help!